# Display form error message on form page

Tags: php

I am trying to display php error message on same page as form but unable to print this.

Form is working and error message is also showing up but the problem is only form redirect on another page.

Here is form.php

```
<form action="contact_mail.php" method="post" name="contact_Form" id="contactform">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 page_subtitle">Get in Touch</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mt-30">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($errors['name_co'])): echo $errors; endif; ?>" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name_co" ></div>              
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><input type="text" id="txtEmail" value="" placeholder="Email ID" class="form-control" name="email_co" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" required /></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" name="mobile" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" required /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><textarea cols="45" rows="6" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" name="comments_co" required/></textarea></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><?php 
                            $a_con=rand(0,9);
                            $b_con=rand(0,9);
                        ?>
         Human Test <?php echo $a_con." + ".$b_con?> = 
                        </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Human Test" class="form-control" name="value_num" required/>
    <input class="input" name="captcha_num_hidden_contact" id="captcha_num_hidden_contact" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a_con+$b_con;?>"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="submit"   name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" /></div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

And here is 
contact_mail.php

```
<?php

$errors = array();    // array to hold validation errors
$data = array();        // array to pass back data
//error_reporting(0);

// validate the variables ======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
if (empty($_POST['name_co']))
  $errors['name_co'] = 'Name is required.';
if (empty($_POST['email_co']))
    $errors['email_co'] = 'Email is required.';

if (empty($_POST['mobile'])){
    $errors['mobile'] = 'Mobile no is required.';
} else if(strlen((string)$_POST['mobile']) < 10){

    $errors['mobile'] = 'Please enter a valid Mobil No.';
}

if (empty($_POST['comments_co']))
    $errors['comments_co'] = 'Comments is required.';


if (empty($_POST['value_num'])) {
    $errors['value_num'] = 'Human Test is required.';
}
else if ($_POST['captcha_num_hidden_contact'] != $_POST['value_num']) {
    $errors['captcha_num_hidden_contact'] = 'Please enter the correct result.';

}
 }
// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if (!empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;

} else {

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

    // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
    // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)



    $email_subject = 'Query From Contact Us';




//    $message = '<div><strong>Query From Contact Us : </strong></div>';
//    $message .= '<div>---------------------------------------- </div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Name: </strong>' . $_POST['name_co'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Email: </strong>' . $_POST['email_co'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Service: </strong>' . $_POST['option_type'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Subject: </strong>' . $_POST['subject_co'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Mobile: </strong>' . $_POST['mobile'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Comments: </strong>' . $_POST['comments_co'] . '</div>';


    $email_subject1 = 'Acknowledgement';


    $headers1 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "From: "."\r\n";
    $mailstatus1 = mail($_POST['email_co'], $email_subject1, $message1, $headers1, "");


    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Your Query has been successfully submit. We will contact you very soon!!';
    header("location:thank-you.php");
      exit;
}
//echo json_encode($data);
// return all our data to an AJAX call
```

My main problem is that I want to print the error message on the form page but I was unable to print it.

Comment: Question is why do you want to print errors on from.php and not on page where they acctualy occur?

Comment: Universus@on submit i want to show error message your captch input is not  wrong. when its submit then its redirect on  contact_mail.php , that why i want error message on form.php on top captcha input

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you are trying to achieve here. I would implement it on one page. I dont know why you have to redirect.

Comment: Universus @I am looking for help please if you can do this plzz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comments I implemented your code on one page.
changed your

```
<form action="contact_mail.php" method="post" name="contact_Form" id="contactform">
```

into

```
<form target="_self" method="post" name="contact_Form" id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and added printing errors as in @Bernhard Answer

```
  echo implode('<br>', $data['errors']);
```

Also changed pattern in this line

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" name="mobile" pattern="[123456789]{9}" required /></div>
```

I am just going to say that when you will be ready consider user input validation in php not just html and using library for sending email such as PHPMailer.

Here is whole code

```
<?php 


$errors = array();    // array to hold validation errors
$data = array();        // array to pass back data
//error_reporting(0);

// validate the variables ======================================================
// if any of these variables don't exist, add an error to our $errors array
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])){   
if (empty($_POST['name_co']))
  $errors['name_co'] = 'Name is required.';
if (empty($_POST['email_co']))
    $errors['email_co'] = 'Email is required.';

if (empty($_POST['mobile'])){
    $errors['mobile'] = 'Mobile no is required.';
} else if(strlen((string)$_POST['mobile']) < 10){

    $errors['mobile'] = 'Please enter a valid Mobil No.';
}

if (empty($_POST['comments_co']))
    $errors['comments_co'] = 'Comments is required.';


if (empty($_POST['value_num'])) {
    $errors['value_num'] = 'Human Test is required.';
}
else if ($_POST['captcha_num_hidden_contact'] != $_POST['value_num']) {
    $errors['captcha_num_hidden_contact'] = 'Please enter the correct result.';

}
 }
// return a response ===========================================================

// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false
if (!empty($errors)) {

    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors'] = $errors;

    echo implode('<br>', $data['errors']);

} else {

    // if there are no errors process our form, then return a message

    // DO ALL YOUR FORM PROCESSING HERE
    // THIS CAN BE WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DO (LOGIN, SAVE, UPDATE, WHATEVER)



    $email_subject = 'Query From Contact Us';




//    $message = '<div><strong>Query From Contact Us : </strong></div>';
//    $message .= '<div>---------------------------------------- </div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Name: </strong>' . $_POST['name_co'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Email: </strong>' . $_POST['email_co'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Service: </strong>' . $_POST['option_type'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Subject: </strong>' . $_POST['subject_co'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Mobile: </strong>' . $_POST['mobile'] . '</div>';
//    $message .= '<div><strong>Comments: </strong>' . $_POST['comments_co'] . '</div>';


    $email_subject1 = 'Acknowledgement';


    $headers1 = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers1 .= "From: "."\r\n";
    $mailstatus1 = mail($_POST['email_co'], $email_subject1, $message1, $headers1, "");


    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Your Query has been successfully submit. We will contact you very soon!!';
    //header("location:thank-you.php");

}


?>


<form target="_self" method="post" name="contact_Form" id="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 page_subtitle">Get in Touch</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row mt-30">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" value="<?php if (isset($errors['name_co'])): echo $errors; endif; ?>" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name_co" ></div>              
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><input type="text" id="txtEmail" value="" placeholder="Email ID" class="form-control" name="email_co" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" required /></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Phone Number" class="form-control" name="mobile" pattern="[123456789]{9}" required /></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><textarea cols="45" rows="6" placeholder="Message" class="form-control" name="comments_co" required/></textarea></div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><?php 
                            $a_con=rand(0,9);
                            $b_con=rand(0,9);
                        ?>
         Human Test <?php echo $a_con." + ".$b_con?> = 
                        </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" value="" placeholder="Human Test" class="form-control" name="value_num" required/>
    <input class="input" name="captcha_num_hidden_contact" id="captcha_num_hidden_contact" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a_con+$b_con;?>"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="submit"   name="submit" class="btn btn-submit" /></div>
          </div>
          </form>
```

Comment: Universus@thanks for this support but this is not working

Comment: Universus@please let me know if any issue

Comment: It works for me. When I fill all the fields and press submit I see "Please enter a valid Mobil No.
Please enter the correct result"

Comment: Universus @page was loaded and need error two  show before validation

Comment: Universus@if you need  teamvivwer connection then i can provide pleas ehelp me regarding this

Comment: Yes there are 2 notices and 1 warning. You have to know why they are here if you want to understand this code. Every programmer gets stuck from time to time. You can try to divide your problem to many small simple pieces. Perhaps start with a form where you have only one field. Watch some step by step tutorial. Read some articles. Maybe step out from problem for day or two. Get some fresh air. But understand this. You have to write code by yourself in order to get better in writing a code.

Comment: Universus@yes  I am agreed with you

Comment: If english is not obstacle to you then from youtube scene I can recommend Derek Banas. That guy is real grandmaster at teaching and he covers wide variety of languages.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. You only need to output the Array with the errors below

```
if (!empty($errors)) {
```

You can do this like so:

```
echo implode('<br>', $data['errors']);
```

implode() will put the array together to a string. 
 is put between each array-element when it is imploded.

Comment: Bernhard@please let me know where i  i have to ingrate this , can you  implement this  with my question

Comment: i already told you above lol@you told me  i know . this is but i was unable to solve this